# assign a flag number to fixed number ofobservations

Tags: sql, sas

I need to assign a flag number starting from 1 to a fixed number of observations in a sas dataset. For example, 1 to observations 1 to 20 then 2 to observations 21 to 40 and so on. How should i proceed in sas datastep or sql query?

Comment: You should use a data step.  This would not be easy using SAS `proc sql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically something to do in a `data`step, not in `proc sql`.

In a `data`step you have the temporary value `_N_`, which is the observation number, which you might use to do this:

```
data myData_flagged;
    set myData;
    flag = int((_N_-1)/20);
run;
```